# jquery.data returning undefined results

Tags: javascript, jquery, attributes, attr, custom-data-attribute

I'm trying to use the `jquery.data` method to retrieve a bunch of item's IDs from a node server and save it for each item as an `attr` or `data` and use it later for updating the item.

But the attribute always returns "undefined".
I tried `.data` and `.attr` and both have the same result. 
To elaborate more: what I'm trying to do is get a list of elements from the server create li tags dynamically for each one, then somehow embed the ID that is coming from the server in each created HTML element as a custom attribute or an ID. 
What am I doing wrong? and is there another way to do this?

```js
var test = "<p>Hello</p>";
$(test).data("id", 1);
console.log($(test).data("id")); //undefined
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 4):

`$(test)` creates an object. So when you want to log the `id`, you are creating another object and tries to read the `data-id` of it, which is absent. Create and keep the object reference in a separate variable and use that in the rest part.

```js
var test = "<p>Hello</p>"
var jTest = $(test);
jTest.data("id", 1);
console.log(jTest.data("id"))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer  that solved the undefined issue, however I'm creating items dynamically on the html page using jquery, so I'm not sure how many items will be created and thus I need the item ID coming from the server to be embedded somehow on each Html element created, that I can use it later to identify which Item to update on the server.
Is there another way to do this that the ID will be embedded in the same object?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is because you're creating two separate `$(test)` jQuery objects. You need to store the reference to the first one in a variable after you set the `data()` on it. Then you can read that value back out again. Try this:

```js
var test = "<p>Hello</p>"
var $test = $(test).data("id", 1); // create reference to the jQuery object
console.log($test.data("id")); // use the reference we created above
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer @Rory, this also does solve the undefined issue, but if the HTML element is clicked I won't be able to retrieve the ID stored by using ($(this).data("id"), that would still return undefined. I'm still new at this so still struggling .